# What are the Physical Stat enhancing versions of 'Tomes'?

Tags: dnd-5e

My players have just broken in to 6th level, where they are starting to fight creatures of 5+ CR ratings.  This opens up the possibility of finding magical items called 'Tomes' that permanently increase one of your 3 mental scores.  These Tomes are the Tome of Thought (Int), Leadership (Cha), and Understanding (Wis).

I am trying to figure out what the versions of these 3 tomes are that permanently increase a players physical scores; Strength, Constitution, and Dexterity.

I have found the 'Belts of ??? Giant Strength' , which increase your Strength depending on rarity; though not permanently like the Tomes do.  I have found nothing (that I can recall) for Constitution or Dexterity.  I am sure they exist, and if they do not then why are the mental stats favored over the physical ones?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They are Manuals of Gainful Exercise, Quickness of Action, and Bodily Health.

Comment: Manuals.  How did I miss these??